# Unable to insert event in to google calendar after access_token received

Tags: google-calendar-api

im trying to insert an event to google calendar via api. I got an access token after that i tried to insert an event with scopes it gives me nothing and there is nothing error and response. Simply stops after receiving access token. Here is my code as follows.

```
  async inItClient() {
      client = await google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        apiKey: API_KEY,
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events',
        access_type: "offline",
        callback: (tokenResponse: any) => {
          const access_token = tokenResponse.access_token;
          console.log('Access Token:' + JSON.stringify(tokenResponse));
              if (tokenResponse && access_token) {
                if (google.accounts.oauth2.hasGrantedAllScopes(tokenResponse,
                  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events')) {
                // Meeting planning and review documents
                gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY);
                gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', this.insertEvents());
              }
          }
        }
      });
      client.requestAccessToken();
  }

  insertEvents() {
    console.log('Calendar called');

    let resource = {
      "summary": "Appointment",
      "location": "Somewhere",
      "start": {
        "dateTime": "2023-04-24T10:00:00.000-07:00"
      },
      "end": {
        "dateTime": "2023-04-24T10:25:00.000-07:00"
      }
    };

    gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
      'calendarId': 'primary',
      'resource': resource
    })

  }
```